# Jupyter dark themes graphs

Tags: python, plot, graph, jupyter

I have jupyter dark themes installed. My graphs sometimes look normal and sometimes it is very hard to read x, y axes. Same matplotlib code gives different results
[Easy to read graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZywW.png)

[Hard to read graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsvch.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set style in matplotlib.
You want `dark_background`

```py
from matplotlib import style
print(style.available)

#['Solarize_Light2',
# '_classic_test_patch',
# 'bmh',
# 'classic',
# 'dark_background',
# 'fast',
# 'fivethirtyeight',
# 'ggplot',
# 'grayscale',
# 'seaborn',
# 'seaborn-bright',
# 'seaborn-colorblind',
# 'seaborn-dark',
# 'seaborn-dark-palette',
# 'seaborn-darkgrid',
# 'seaborn-deep',
#'seaborn-muted',
# 'seaborn-notebook',
# 'seaborn-paper',
# 'seaborn-pastel',
# 'seaborn-poster',
# 'seaborn-talk',
#'seaborn-ticks',
# 'seaborn-white',
# 'seaborn-whitegrid',
# 'tableau-colorblind10']
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use the plot function, do something like this.

```
ax = df.plot()  # whatever type
```

Then to change the color of the axes, you can use this function.

```
ax.tick_params(color='w', labelcolor='w')
```

It will change the color of the labels to white, you can use any other color you like; refer to the documentation for that.